# Get parameters outside of Grouping Linq

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

I need to get some Field's out of the Group using linq for example, this is my code:

```
(from PaymentTypes in PaymentTypes_DataTable.AsEnumerable()
join CashTransactions in CashTransactions_DataTable.AsEnumerable()
    on PaymentTypes.Field<Int32>("cashpaymenttype_id")
    equals CashTransactions.Field<Int32>("cashpaymenttype_id")
    into JoinedCashTransactions
from CashTransactions in JoinedCashTransactions.DefaultIfEmpty()
group CashTransactions by PaymentTypes.Field<Int32>("cashpaymenttype_id")
into GroupPaymentTypes
select new
{
    cashpaymenttype_id = 0, // Get PaymentTypeID
    cashpaymenttype_name = "", // Get PaymentTypeName
    cashtransaction_amount = GroupPaymentTypes.Sum(a =>
       a != null
          ? (a.Field<Int32>("cashtransactionstatus_id") == 1 ||
            a.Field<Int32>("cashtransactionstatus_id") == 3 ? 1 : -1) *
            a.Field<Double>("cashtransaction_amount") 
          : 0.00),
}).Aggregate(PaymentTypesTransactions_DataTable, (dt, result) => { 
    dt.Rows.Add(result.cashpaymenttype_id, result.cashpaymenttype_name,
   result.cashtransaction_amount); return dt; });
```

This linq works but i need to get the fields `cashpaymenttype_id` and `cashpaymenttype_name` they are within `PaymentTypes`

Comment: There is no *one* value for those fields.  There are a *bunch* of items, all with potentially different values of those fields.  You can get a *list* of those values, or you can aggregate them in some way (such as the `Sum` you use on the other field) to turn them into a single value, but there is no one way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming PaymentTypeID - PaymentTypeName is 1-to-1, you could change your group by to this:

```
group CashTransactions by new 
{ 
    PaymentTypeId = PaymentTypes.Field<Int32>("cashpaymenttype_id"),
    PaymentTypeName = PaymentTypes.Field<String>("cashpaymenttype_name")
}
into GroupPaymentTypes
```

The your select will look like this:

```
select new
{
    cashpaymenttype_id = GroupPaymentTypes.Key.PaymentTypeId, 
    cashpaymenttype_name = GroupPaymentTypes.Key.PaymentTypeName, 
    ...
}
```